# Copy column,add some text and write in a new csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to make a script that would copy 2nd column from multiple csv files in a folder and add some text before saving it to a single csv file .

here is what i want to do :

1.) Grab data in the 2nd column from all csv files

2.) Append text "hello" & "welcome" to each row at start and end

3.) Write the data into a single file

I tried creating it using pandas

```
import os
import pandas as pd
dataframes = [pd.read_csv(p, index_col=2, header=None) for p in ('1.csv','2.csv','3.csv')]
merged_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=0)
merged_dataframe.to_csv("all.csv", index=False)
```

The Problem is -

1. In above code I am forced to mention the file names manually which is very difficult, as a solution I need to include all csv file `*.csv`
2. Need to use something like `writr.writerow(("Hello"+r[1]+"welcome"))`
3. As there are multiple csv files with many rows(around 100k) in each file so i need to speed up as well.

Here is a sample of the csv files:

```
 "1.csv"        "2.csv"            "3.csv"
  a,Jac          b,William          c,James
```

And here is how I would like the output to look all.csv:

```
Hello Jac welcome
Hello William welcome
Hello James welcome
```

Any solution using `.merge()` `.append()` or `.concat()` ??

How can I achieve this using python ?

Comment: Hi Nancy. You can get all the csv files with the module glob like this: `paths = glob.glob('foo/*.csv')`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need pandas for this. Here's a really simple way of doing this with `csv`

```
import csv
import glob


with open("path/to/output", 'w') as outfile:
    for fpath in glob.glob('path/to/directory/*.csv'):
        with open(fpath) as infile:
            for row in csv.reader(infile):
                outfile.write("Hello {} welcome\n".format(row[1]))
```

Comment: wouldn't pandas speed up the job?

Comment: @Nancy: I can't say with certainty, but I don't think you'll get "enough" of a speedup with Pandas for this application - you're still bottlenecked by writing the output

Answer (score 0):

1) If you would like to import all .csv files in a folder, you can just use

```
for i in [a in os.listdir() if a[-4:] == '.csv']:
    #code to read in .csv file and concatenate to existing dataframe
```

2) To append the text and write to a file, you can map a function to each element of the dataframe's column 2 to add the text.

```
#existing dataframe called df
df[df.columns[1]].map(lambda x: "Hello {} welcome".format(x)).to_csv(<targetpath>)
#replace <targetpath> with your target path
```

See http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html for all the various parameters you can pass in to `to_csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a non-pandas solution using built in csv module. Not sure about speed.

```
import os
import csv

path_to_files = "path to files"
all_csv = os.path.join(path_to_files, "all.csv")
file_list = os.listdir(path_to_files)

names = []

for file in file_list:
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        path_to_current_file = os.path.join(path_to_files, file)

        with open(path_to_current_file, "r") as current_csv:
            reader = csv.reader(current_csv, delimiter=',')

            for row in reader:
                names.append(row[1])

with open(all_csv, "w") as out_csv:
    writer = csv.writer(current_csv, delimiter=',')

    for name in names:
        writer.writerow(["Hello {} welcome".format(name))
```